# Proper non-trivial ideal question.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism from $R$ to $R'$ there exists a proper non-trivial ideal $N$ of $R$. I want to show that $\phi(N)$ is as well and proper non-trivial ideal, but of $\phi(R)$. I have been able to do the first step, showing that $\phi(N)$ is just an ideal of $\phi(R)$, but I am struggling to show that $\phi(N)$ is not the trivial ideal and proper ideal.

Comment: $\phi[N]$ could be a trivial ideal. E.g. if the homomorphism is into the trivial ring, of the ideal $2\mathbb{Z}$ in the homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Is there any way to prove that () cannot be the trivial ideal? I am asking this again because the original question I posted was I question I received as homework from my professor.

Comment: There is no way to prove it because it is false. I would check that you've read the question correctly, then ask the professor for clarification.

Comment: Suppose N properly contains more than the ker(). Would that change anything?

Comment: Yes, that completely changes it. Then $\phi[N]$ is not trivial.

Comment: Okay, awesome! How would that work? I understand that all elements of the ker() would also be contained in N, would that imply ker() = {k in N : phi(k) = 0}?

Comment: $ker(\phi)$ just means the elements that $\phi$ sends to $0$, so $N$ containing elements not in $ker(\phi)$ means $\phi[N]$ contains elements other than $0$.

Comment: So, the argument is purely, since N properly contains () there must exist elements in () that are not zero.

Comment: $N$ doesn't need to properly contain it. There just needs to be an element of $N$ not in the kernel. Just think through the definition of the kernel.

Comment: How would this also imply that, given the additional information of $ker(\phi)$ is properly contained in N, $\phi(N)$ is also proper?